# what do paypal agreement transaction states mean?

Tags: recurring, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using the PayPal rest API recurring payment.
About [Agreement Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#search-for-transactionsk), it has many states i.e.: Completed, Expired, Pending.

What do they mean and when they appear?

Answer (score 0):

**Completed** – successful payment, done and confirmed. **Expired** – recurring payment that has ended. **Pending** – payment that needs confirmation (or is checking at the moment)

Also you can read this FAQ https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/

There are a few moments with account settings (like currencies f.e.) you should set to minimize the pending time. Hope that helps.

Comment: What is transaction's state if my paypal account has not enough money to pay? And what 's continue if I fill up money?